# sql query by using join only

Tags: sql, oracle

List the `emp`s Whose `job`s are same as MILLER's `job` or `sal` is more than ALLEN's `sal`.

the above question is a  common question of oracle sql. the answer by using sub queries has been solved. but the solution of  this question by using only join will be ?

```
select *  from emp  where job =  (select  job from emp where ename =
'MILLER' ) or  sal>(select sal from emp where ename = 'ALLEN');
```

Comment: This is clearly an assignment question, as it even still has the curly quotes copied from another website or doc. Please post what you have attempted, and where you are stuck. We're happy to assist you out of a difficult corner, but won't provide exam or assignment answers in entirety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * from emp e1 join emp e2
where (e2.Ename = 'Miller' and e1.job = e2.job) 
or (e2.Ename = 'Allen' and e1.sal > e2.sal)
```